# R Shiny - Pass user input (text and uploaded image) as parameter to generate report

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to create a shiny application that allows users to enter text and upload an image.  I would then like the text inputted by the user and image uploaded by the user to be downloaded as an html report in a similar format only with the headings, text, and image.  My aim is to have multiple text boxes and associated images in a report that is downloaded.

I have the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)

ui <-
fluidPage(
    titlePanel("QA Template"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('HTML'),
                         inline = TRUE),
            downloadButton('downloadReport')
        )),

mainPanel(
fluidRow(
    h2("Presentation"),
column(5,h4("Titles"),
    textAreaInput("inText", "Do titles properly convey 
content?",height='100px',width='400px')),
column(1,h4("Upload Image"),
    fileInput("file1",label="",
    accept = c('image/png', 'image/jpeg','image/jpg')
    )),
column(4,offset = 1,imageOutput('p1')))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

inText<-reactive({textAreaInput()})
output$inText<-renderText({textAreaInput()})
file1 <- reactive({gsub("\\\\", "/", input$file1$datapath)})
output$p1<-renderImage({list(src = file1())})

downloadHandler(
filename = 
    paste("QA_report","file",".html",sep=""),
    content = function(file) {
    tempReport<-file.path(tempdir(),"QA_report.Rmd")

    file.copy('QA_report.Rmd', tempReport,overwrite = TRUE)
    ##Parameters to pass
    params <- list(text1=inText,pic1=file1)

rmarkdown::render(tempReport,output_file=file, params=params,
envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
      }  
)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also have this in the .Rmd:

````
---
title: "QA Template"
output: html_document
params:
  text1: NA
  pic1: NA
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```

### Presentation

## Titles

# Do titles properly convey content?

```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
print(params[["text1"]])
```

```{r, results='asis',echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE} 
knitr::include_graphics(params[["pic1"]])
```
````

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: I have tried the above code and it produces the text box without user inputs and the image upload dialog without the uploaded image.  I would like the downloaded file to be a .html file with the text inputted in the shiny app and the image uploaded in the shiny app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small quirk with using `renderImage()` we need to set the `deleteFile` flag to `FALSE`. Otherwise, the file is read into the temp directory, displayed for the user and then deleted.

Not sure what you were trying to do here but it looks wrong `textAreaInput` is a UI function. You need to refer to the text flowing into the server with `input$inText` not `output$inText` or `textAreaInput()`

```
inText<-reactive({textAreaInput()})
output$inText<-renderText({textAreaInput()})
```

Here is the working code,

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)

ui <-fluidPage(
    titlePanel("QA Template"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('HTML'),
                     inline = TRUE),
        downloadButton('downloadReport')
      ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        h2("Presentation"),
        column(5,h4("Titles"),
               textAreaInput("inText", "Do titles properly convey 
content?",height='100px',width='400px')),
        column(1,h4("Upload Image"),
               fileInput("file1",label="",
                         accept = c('image/png', 'image/jpeg','image/jpg')
               )),
        column(4,offset = 1,imageOutput('p1'))
        )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  file1 <- reactive({gsub("\\\\", "/", input$file1$datapath)})

  output$p1<-renderImage({
    req(file1())
    browser()
    list(src = file1())
    },deleteFile = FALSE)


  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 
      paste("QA_report","file",".html",sep=""),
    content = function(file) {
      tempReport<-file.path(tempdir(),"QA_report.Rmd")
      file.copy('QA_report.Rmd', tempReport,overwrite = TRUE)
      ##Parameters to pass
      params <- list(text1=input$inText,pic1=file1())
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport,output_file=file, params=params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    }  
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```